# Getting stackoverflowerror from Gson while converting hashmap to JSON object

Tags: json, hashmap, gson

I want to represent data in tree structure as java object then I want to convert it to JSON object.

With the help of stackoverflow entries:

[Convert java arrayList of Parent/child relation into tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30570146/convert-java-arraylist-of-parent-child-relation-into-tree/30570416#30570416)

[hashmap to JSON using GSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39657154/hashmap-to-json-using-gson)

I had below main function and "pairs" list contains a pair: child and parent

```
ArrayList<Pair> list= new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Pair("6", "4"));
list.add(new Pair("5", "4"));
list.add(new Pair("4", "3"));
list.add(new Pair("2", "3"));
list.add(new Pair("3", "null"));

Map<String, Node> o_map= new HashMap<>();
for (Pair l: list) {
Node parent = o_map.getOrDefault(l.getParentId(), new Node(l.getParentId()));
Node child = o_map.getOrDefault(l.getChildId(), new Node(l.getChildId()));
parent.children.add(child);
child.parent = parent;
o_map.put(parent.id, parent);
o_map.put(child.id, child);
}
Gson gs = new Gson();
System.out.println(gs.toJson(o_map));
}
```

However this code returns:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:112)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.string(JsonWriter.java:576)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.writeDeferredName(JsonWriter.java:402)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.beginArray(JsonWriter.java:287)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:95)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:112)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:239)
    at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:968)
```

error.

I don't get why it returns such an error. 
What could be the reason?
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What I need to do is to convert a hashmap<String, List<String>> to json object.

Comment: shouldnt you write it like this `ArrayList<Pair> list= new ArrayList<Pair>();`

Comment: I need to have tree structure in json. To do that I need to have hashmap converted to json. I tried the other alternative, writing a pair list to json, but outcome wasn't what I look for.

Comment: "*outcome wasn't what I look for*" - it's helpful to share what outcome you *are* looking for. Including the definition of `Node` would also be helpful, since that's what you're trying to serialize.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't include your `Node` class definition, but I'm guessing it looks something like this:

```
public class Node {
  public final String id;
  public Node parent;
  public final ArrayList<Node> children = new ArrayList<>();

  public Node(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}
```

This is a fine way to represent a tree data structure *in memory* (ignoring some unrelated style issues like using public fields), but it's impossible to serialize. Why? Because any `Node` with a non-null `parent` has a cyclical relationship - a child contains a reference to its parent, which in turn contains a reference to the child, which in turn contains a reference to the parent, which in turn contains .....

From the [user guide](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#object-examples):

> Note that you can not serialize objects with circular references since that will result in infinite recursion.

We can trigger the same error with this simpler example:

```
Node root = new Node("A");
Node child = new Node("B");
root.children.add(child);
child.parent = root;
System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(root)); // passing in child would similarly fail
```

So how can we fix this? It depends on what behavior you want. One easy option is to prevent Gson from attempting to serialize the `parent` field (we don't need it, as we can reconstruct it from the `children` list). To do this just [mark `parent` as `transient`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4802887/113632) and Gson will not include it in the result. You could similarly make `children` the `transient` field if explicitly recording the parent relationship is more helpful. A benefit of serializing the `children` field however is that you can just pass in the root node and the whole tree will be traversed.

Another option is to serialize a different data structure than `Map<String, Node>` - you're currently mapping each node ID to its `Node` object (which, transitively, contains a reference to every other node), meaning that even if you fix the cyclical relationship you're still going to get some odd JSON as a result. It *seems* like what you'd really want is to just serialize the ID -> parent or ID -> children relationships, which would be a `Map<String, String>` or `Map<String, List<String>>` data structure which Gson will have no trouble serializing. If that's the structure you want you could simply traverse your tree and construct such a data structure first, or define a [custom deserializer](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization) which converts a `Node` into the exact JSON structure you want.